# Нужны ли кавычки в данном случае?

Tags: кавычки

Нужны ли здесь кавычки, подскажите, пожалуйста, если да, то почему?
*Это ряд «В». Он сказал, что нам нужен ряд «Е».*
И нужны ли кавычки, если ряд, либо место обозначены цифрами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нужны ли кавычки?**

Вопрос философский, и в правилах Розенталя он вряд ли рассматривается. Такие задачи решаются самостоятельно.

1. Для начала можно заглянуть "в чужую тетрадь"  –  как другие-то пишут?

Вот **математики** ни за что кавычки не поставят, у них все строго: Из точки А проведены две касательные к окружности с центром в точке О.

И действительно, зачем здесь кавычки, какую функцию они выполняют? Если разделительную (выделительную), то прописная буква вполне с этим справляется.

2. Но, может быть, это **имя собственное**, то есть название чего-либо, например: *Четыре трибуны стадиона подразделяются на «А»; «В»; «С» и «D», соответствующие другим названиям, как «Запад»; «Север»; «Восток» и «Юг»*. В данном предложении, похоже, кавычки нужны, но именно **при перечислении** (разделительная функция).

Но вот другая запись: *Самыми удобными на мой взгляд места находятся в секторах А4 и А5, но они самые дорогие. Можно посмотреть по схеме мест поближе к ним, но немного с края на трибуне А или напротив на трибуне С.* Здесь нет кавычек.

3. А как **в художественной литературе**? Тоже по-разному.

*Люди почти счастливы… Они считают себя свободными, потому что могут сами выбрать маршрут перехода из точки А в точку Б. Хотя на самом деле никакой точки Б нет, а есть только, как говорят у вас сибирские урки, те же яйца при виде сбоку…* [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

*А иногда думаешь: как замечательно, что есть современные средства перемещения моего тела из точки «А» в точку «Б» за считаные часы.* [З. Е. Гердт. Рыцарь совести (2010)]

4. Получается, что у нас **ситуативное решение**, и автор выбирает его сам:

*Это ряд «В». Он сказал, что нам нужен ряд «Е».*

Да, кавычки здесь необязательны, но смотрятся неплохо. Так что я бы поставила: пусть это будет названием рядов. Все-таки не математика же!